# SQL Server 2008 : Updating a column based on other tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, count

**TableA** (`id int, match char(15), multiple char(10)`)

```
int match multiple
1   100  
2   101
3   102
4   103
```

**TableB** (`match char(15), match2 char(10)`)

```
match  match2
100    ABC
100    NBG
101    NYF
102    NHW
102    UYQ
103    WOT
```

Now, I want to populate `TableA.multiple = "YES"` if in `TableB` for corresponding match, there exists more than one match2.

Expected result.

```
int match multiple
1   100    YES
2   101    NULL
3   102    YES
4   103    NULL
```

Thanks in advance !

My FAILED try:

```
Update A 
SET multiple = 'YES' 
From tableA A
Inner join tableB B ON A.match = B.match
WHERE (Select count(distinct(B.match2)) from TableB) > 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with an extra-verbose version, just for its clarity:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET multiple = 'YES'
WHERE match in (
    -- isolate the multiples
    SELECT match from (
        -- count the matches
        SELECT count(*) as c, match from TableB
        GROUP BY match ) x
    WHERE c > 1
)
```

With the HAVING clause, you can change this...

```
    SELECT match from (
        SELECT count(*) as c, match from TableB
        GROUP BY match ) x
    WHERE c > 1
```

...to this:

```
   SELECT match from TableB
   GROUP BY match
   HAVING count(*) > 1
```

So now we have:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET multiple = 'YES'
WHERE match in (
   SELECT match from TableB
   GROUP BY match
   HAVING count(*) > 1
)
```

I'm sure it can be made more compact, but I personally get confused by `UPDATE` statements containing non-obvious `JOIN` clauses, especially in the middle of the night when I get the call that "the database isn't working!"

[Don't Make Me Think](http://www.sensible.com/dmmt.html) applies to coding, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tableA
SET multiple = 'YES'
FROM TableA AS a
JOIN (SELECT match FROM tableB GROUP BY match HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS b ON a.match = b.match
```

Comment: This idea is good, but it will give a slow performance in many situations.

Answer (score -3):

```
UPDATE TableA a
SET multiple='YES'
FROM Tablea a,(SELECT match FROM Tableb GROUP BY match HAVING COUNT(*)>1)b
WHERE a.match=b.match
```

Comment: I need to populate YES when there are more than 1 (match2) records for same match in tableA

Comment: This wont work as the number is not taken into consideration.

Comment: @BhupinderSingh Check this one.

Comment: You should use explicit JOIN syntax.

Comment: Venk - You edited it, before it was edited the results might have worked but it would not give the expected results.  Also you should still use explicit join syntax.

Comment: In my b alias.. I am considering only those matches which have count more than 1. I am just joining it with Tablea and updating it.May be my query might be costly but its not wrong..

Comment: @Venk - You are not reading this correctly.  Please read what I posted.  No where in my post did I say this does not work, before your edit.

Comment: "it would not give the expected results" What does it mean?

Comment: -1 Implicit syntax is a SQL antipattern it should  not be encouraged